# sudo apt-get update error: E: Splitting of file /var/lib/apt/lists/si.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt

```
Hit:1 http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:2 http:// si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http:// si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http:// download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease        
Err:3 http:// si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease           
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/si.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-backports_InRelease into data and signature failed
Hit:5 https:// updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease           
Get:6 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78,6 kB]
Hit:7 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit:8 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main i386 Packages
Hit:9 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main Translation-en
Hit:10 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Hit:11 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Hit:12 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit:13 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit:14 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe Translation-en
Hit:15 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Hit:16 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Hit:17 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:8 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:15 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit:18 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit:19 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:7 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:8 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main i386 Packages     
Ign:9 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main Translation-en
Hit:10 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:10 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe Translation-en
Hit:15 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:15 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:7 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 Packages [72,5 kB]
Ign:18 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse Translation-en
Get:8 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main i386 Packages [71,1 kB]
Get:9 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main Translation-en [33,2 kB]
Get:12 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe i386 Packages [20,5 kB]
Hit:10 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:13 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 Packages [20,5 kB]
Ign:10 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:14 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe Translation-en [12,5 kB]
Get:17 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1257 B]
Hit:15 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:18 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1075 B]
Get:19 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse Translation-en [644 B]
Ign:15 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:10 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Ign:15 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Fetched 78,6 kB in 2s (27,0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Error!
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/si.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-backports_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-backports/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/si.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-backports_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Empty files can't be valid archives
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Splitting of file /var/lib/apt/lists/si.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-backports_InRelease failed as it doesn't contain all expected parts 0 1 0
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This is what I'm seeing when I try to run `sudo apt-get update`. I didn't use computer for 1 month.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

in order to remove all the lists and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to download the lists again

Comment: ok, I was worried about an `rm -r` but It didn't fix my issue until I deleted all the contents of the lists folder.

Answer (score 20):

This just happened on my system too, and the reason was my `/tmp` disk was full.

After removing some files from `/tmp`, `apt-get update` started working again.

I also added a bug report at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1822462)

Comment: What the actual blyad it worked for me too <3 thx man

Answer (score 4):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Did not work for me, when encountered this error.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if your `/tmp` directory is full.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well when I ran apt update. After trying all the other recommendations listed here (such as deleting contents of `/tmp`). I happened to discover that the disk my OS was on was completely full:

I removed some unneeded data on the disk and was able to run apt update successfully. So, if all else fails, you can check this.